# How to accessing a JSON from a URL and extract the data into blade Using Javascript

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem extracting the data into html file, The data are from database and it's already encode in the Controller of Laravel, **So now the problem how to extract the data into my customer_data.blade.php using Fetch of javascript**

**I have here the public function customer:**

```
public function customer() {

     $select_menu = DB::select('SELECT menu_cat_id,menu_cat_name,menu_cat_desc,menu_cat_price,menu_cat_image FROM menu_category WHERE menu_cat_status = ?',[
        'Active'
    ]);
     $select_menu_decode = json_decode(json_encode($select_menu),true);

     dd($select_menu_decode);
}
```

[image: Encoded]

**My customer_data public function:**

```
public function customer_data() {

    return View('customer_data');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass in data as an array as described [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views)

```
    public function customer_data() {

        $select_menu = DB::select('SELECT menu_cat_id,menu_cat_name,menu_cat_desc,menu_cat_price,menu_cat_image FROM menu_category WHERE menu_cat_status = ?',[
        'Active'
    ]);        
        return View('customer_data', ['menu'=>$select_menu]);
    }
```

which you would then be able to access in the view template as:

```
@foreach( $menu as $item )
    <li><a href="#">{{ $item->menu_cat_name }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: hi steerpike, how to loop it in foreach?

Comment: also steerpike,  why you use the variable $select_menu rather than the $select_menu_decode

Comment: Because as the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database) stipulate select() will always return an array of results (each result will be a stdClass object). Why not just use what you're given rather than running it back and forth through json_encode/decode

Comment: Hi pike, my point here is i want to extract the api to the html file.

Comment: Hi Steerpike sorry for the wrong description, I update my question so you understand my question well, I just want to ask is how to fetch my api http://localhost:8000/api/customer to the customer_data? using the fetch function of javascript